# How to sort files in python in numeric order?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm creating pdf file from images but having problem with sorting the jpg files in numeric order
I have 20 files from 1.jpg to 20.jpg
I'm using below code to sort all files in order

```
import os
sorted(os.listdir('path/to/jpg/files'))
```

but it will print 1.jpg, 11.jpg, 12.jpg and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: `sorted(os.listdir('path/to/jpg/files'), key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorted` takes a key. You can use `lambda` function in the key to do a numeric order sort.

**Ex:**

```
import os
sorted(os.listdir('path/to/jpg/files'), key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))
```